# sorting an array in python jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas

When I try to sort an array in jupyter notebook using the following syntax, it sorts all rows rather than a single row, throwing the indexes are off.

ADELAIDE = df.groupby('Year')['Passengers_Total'].sum()

What syntax should I use to only sort the 'Passengers_Total' column?

Comment: Can you add a minimal code example, including creation of the dataframe as well as the specific desired output?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv("Totals.csv",sep=',')

Comment: df8 = df.loc[df['AustralianPort']=='Adelaide]

Comment: desired output would be 2 columns, one with year and one with Passengers_total, where it sorts the list in descending order, and the year still corresponds to that Passengers_total value

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to sort only 'Passengers_Total column' only.

`result = df.sort([''Passengers_Total'], ascending=[0])`